# Como crear una piramide de asteriscos en una function dando yo el numero de las que quiera crear

Tags: javascript

quiero saber como puedo crear una piramide de asteriscos dando yo la cantidad y este la imprima. A continuación muestro el codigo el cual imprime 5 estrellas, lo que quiero hacer es meterla dentro de una función para que cuando le cambie el valor en me imprima esa cantidad de asteriscos.

```
 let z = "";
 let y = 0;
 let x = "*";
 while (y < 5) {
   z += x;
   console.log(z + "");
   y++;
 }
```

algo asi:

```
function zz() {
  let z = "";
  let y = 0;
  let x = "*";
  while (y < yy) {
    z += x;
    y++;
  }
  console.log(yy + "");
}
var yy = 10;
```

Comment: Revisa esta publicación https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738935/how-to-display-pyramid-using-javascript

Comment: @LordXedriantheHigher y que te importa eso a ti? Tiene un problema y está pidiendo ayuda. Lamentable comentario el tuyo, haciendo que el mio también lo sea

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente pasale el numero de asteriscos como parametro

```js
function zz(param) {
      let z = "";
      let y = 0;
      let x = "*";
      while (y < param) {
        z += x;
        console.log(z + "");
        y++;
      }
      
    }
zz(10);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!